# There are multiple dependencies with different sources for `react-native-google-maps` in `Podfile`:

Tags: ios, cocoapods

trying to run `yarn bootstrap` in the example project of this repo https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps and i am getting the following error

```
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
Analyzing dependencies
[!] There are multiple dependencies with different sources for `react-native-google-maps` in `Podfile`:

- react-native-google-maps (from `../..`)
- react-native-google-maps (from `../../`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this in podfile

```
rn_maps_path = '../../'
 pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
```

To this

```
rn_maps_path = '../..'
 pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
```

Comment: that did seem to be the solution. Interestingly enough it was working on a co- workers computer